# How to get current document path to clipboard in Microsoft Office applications?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word, microsoft-office, path, clipboard

How I can get full path of current document into clipboard when working with Microsoft Office applications? I'm mostly interested in Word and Excel.

Example:

I have open the following file in Excel:

```
D:\Data\Customer\Contoso\2014-12-01_Specifications.xlsx
```

Expected result in clipboard after getting the path:

```
D:\Data\Customer\Contoso\2014-12-01_Specifications.xlsx
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Place **Document Location** textbox on the Quick Access Toolbar. When you click there the full path can be copied.

How-to: In **Excel Options** window -> **Quick Access Toolbar** section, you can find this element in group **Commands Not in the Ribbon**. Highlight it and click **Add >>** button.

Described in [How-To Show The Location of a File in the Quick Access Toolbar](http://www.groovypost.com/howto/howto/show-file-path-in-office-2010-quick-access-toolbar/).

Comment: I accepted this answer because it gives "heavy-duty" solution. For whoever who doesn't like adding field to toolbar, you can use one-off answer for [Office 2010+](http://superuser.com/a/877131/287473) or [Office 2003-2007](http://superuser.com/a/877152/287473). Coders can try [this](http://superuser.com/a/877114/287473).

Comment: This is the most efficient method suggested so far. After adding Document Location to Quick Access, you can copy the path to the clipboard using Alt+<Number>, Ctrl+C.

Answer (score 1):

Excel maybe you can use this function (I can't test it):

```
LEFT(CELL("filename"),FIND("]",CELL("filename"),1))
```

For path without name of file:

```
cell("filename")
```

In Excel VBA you can use:

```
ThisWorkbook.Path
```

VBA complet and tested:

```
Sub aaaaa()
MsgBox ActiveDocument.Path & Application.PathSeparator & _
 ActiveDocument.Name
End Sub
```

Comment: maybe use also this [link](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/CellWorksheetFunctions.aspx)

Comment: These are working, BUT I'm trying to imagine my attempts to recall the correct formula or VBA statement if I'm in hurry and need just that path quickly. Was it `Document` or `ThisDocument` or `Workbook` or `ThisWorkbook`? :)

Comment: I edit my post, just look.

Comment: that `Sub` is nice but VBA macros attached to application throw warnings on every application launch because I have no certificates etc... Didn't Microsoft built in some easy out-of-the-box way achievable without coding?

Comment: Finally, [I've found proper way](http://superuser.com/a/877131/287473) which needs only clicking the mouse.

Answer (score 1):

I found the feature available for this purpose since Office 2007.
The steps below can be used in **Office 2010 and higher** :

1. Open **File** backstage menu.
2. Click **Properties** at the top of the rightmost column.
3. Click **Show Document Panel** menu item.
4. At top right corner of **Document panel**, there is a **Location** field.
5. Copy content of the field into the clipboard.

Comment: For older Office versions, see [Tyler's answer](http://superuser.com/a/877152/287473).

Answer (score 1):

In both Microsoft Word and Excel, you can get the path to the current document in the **Document Information Panel**.

Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>

The path to the current document is in the **Location** field in the top, right-hand corner. Triple-click the path and copy it to your clipboard as desired.

Verified on Word/Excel 2003/2007 on Windows.

Comment: A nice solution for older versions of Office. [• Answer for Office 2010+](http://superuser.com/a/877131/287473.)